# yii2 jui datepicker doesn't working on pjax

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

i need datepicker on yii2 gridview. So i have used the jui extension. It was working fine. But when i go for pjax it automatically reloads the page every time when i change the datepicker value. If anyone knows about this please guide me.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
        use yii\helpers\Url;
        use yii\helpers\Html;
        use yii\grid\GridView;
        use yii\widgets\Pjax;
        use yii\jui\DatePicker;
        use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

        Pjax::begin();
        echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel'   => $searchModel,
            'columns'       => [
                ['class'        => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                [
                    'attribute' =>  'td_created_datetime',
                    'filter'        =>  \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
                        'model'         =>  $searchModel,
                        'attribute'     =>  'td_created_datetime',
                        'language'      =>  'en',
                        'dateFormat'    =>  'yyyy-MM-dd',
                        'clientEvents'  => [
                            'change'        => "function(e){ 
                                alert('occured');
                                e.preventDefault(); 
                            }"
                        ],
                    ]),
                ],
            ],
        ]); 
        Pjax::end();
    ?>
```

Comment: In firebug/console view displayed any error message?

Comment: I didn't any error on the console